# Why can I use expect expect().toBeInTheDocument from "@testing-library/jest-dom" if I'm not importing it?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, jest-dom

I create a React.js App with "create React App" and I'm learning to run tests.

Why in the below code I can use `expect().toBeInTheDocument` if I am not importing `@testing-library/jest-dom`?

```
import {render, screen} from "@testing-library/react";
import Greeting from "./Greeting";

test("renders Hello World as a text", () => {
    
    render(<Greeting/>);    
    const helloWorld = screen.getByText('Hello World');
    expect(helloWorld).toBeInTheDocument

});
```

Comment: `expect(helloWorld).toBeInTheDocument` should be `expect(helloWorld).toBeInTheDocument()`. If you don't call the matcher, nothing happens. I suggest using a linter.

Answer (score 1):

When you run `create react app` it creates a file named `setup-test.js` (or `.ts` if you use TypeScript) in your `src` directory which import  `@testing-library/jest-dom` there

This file is loaded by jest (`create-react-app` configured it to do so) before running the tests (I assume using the config `setupFiles`)